# Does Mathematica provide functionality that would be useful for computer network administration, server administration, or IT security

Tags: reference-request

A friend of mine recently purchased the home edition of Mathematica 11 and was demonstrating it to me.

It looks like a useful tool for fields such as AI and perhaps also for processing data. But I got curious on whether it provides any functionality that could be useful for IT fields such as:

- network administration
- server administration
- IT security

Here I am mainly interested in the modeling-related functionality of Mathematica (not so much the programming language as other languages exist for that).

Are there any examples of how the modelling-related features of Mathematica can be used in these fields?

Comment: The question is a bit too broad. *Mathematica* is a general-purpose programming language, so you can use it for these tasks. But it is not as well optimized for interacting with other programs/systems as certain alternatives such as Python, so it will perhaps be better suited to more abstract tasks such as modelling. So the question for you is, really, what sort of tasks do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @OleksandrR, I have now added more details to limit the question specifically to the modelling related functionality.

Comment: Still too broad for me; what exactly do you wish to model? A LAN? The entire Internet?